# Cosets and Lagrange's Theorem

Tags: abelian-groups

This question is under the topic of Cosets and lagrange theorem. Now Is it true that if $G$ is a group that contains a subgroup $H_1$ of order $n$ and a subgroup $H_2$ of order $k$, then $G$ must contain a subgroup of order $nk$?
Really need an example for this proof

Answer (score 2):

No; the easiest counterexample is to take a group $G$ of order $n > 1$, letting $H_1 = H_2 = G$.

Answer (score 0):

Your result would hold if $G$ was abelian and the orders of $H_{1}$ and $H_{2}$ were coprime, but that is a fairly restrictive condition!